# What if there's a global function named "describe" or "it" when using test frameworks like jasmine or mocha

Tags: javascript, jasmine, mocha.js

It's well known that declaring too many global function or variable is not a good practice. But in Jasmine and Mocha, function like "describe" and "it", why do they prefer global functions? Maybe I havn't fully understood them?
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main answer is because it is easier and faster to write.They are also potentially used in environments that don't have modules, like the browser, so if you load jasmine, then a global is the only way to access the jasmine logic.

It also arises in this case because the style that Jasmine and Mocha tests are written lends itself to declarative syntax, so you can almost thing of `describe` and `it` as syntax for tests, rather than as JS functions.

Comment: Your answer seems more reasonable, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Global functions aren't always bad, it just depends on the context.

In the context of a "normal" web application, you can pollute the global scope pretty easily if you don't define things locally. That's why we use things like closures, object literals, etc.

Jasmine and Mocha use global functions because that's what is easiest, and the global functions directly define the unique syntax of those frameworks.  In that context, you're probably not worried about a unit testing framework polluting a global scope.

Plus, it would be hard to write unit tests if you had to do something like:

```
Jasmine.functions.unit.testing.basic.it("should do this", function() {
    // etc.
});
```

That's a bit of an exaggeration, but you get the point.

Comment: We can consider this mode:

Comment: Maybe we can consider adding these codes to Mocha:
(function(it){
  //user codes
})(Jasmine.functions.unit.testing.basic.it)